# How to use symfony2 twig extension without symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to use some of the builtin symfony2 extensions(e.g:humanize,yaml_dump) for twig for a website not developed in symfony but using a twig engine.how can I do that?

Comment: Have you checked the twig (not the symfony) manual?  It shows how to add extensions. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#using-extensions

Comment: yes but I don't know how to access the builtin extensions of symfony2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`symfony/twig-bridge`](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/twig-bridge) package provides the symfony-specific twig extensions.

These include i.e. the [YamlExtension](https://github.com/symfony/TwigBridge/blob/master/Extension/YamlExtension.php) that provides the `yaml_dump` filter and the [FormExtension](https://github.com/symfony/TwigBridge/blob/v2.3.0/Extension/FormExtension.php#L83) that provides the `humanize` filter.

The extensions can be found in the [`Extension`](https://github.com/symfony/TwigBridge/tree/master/Extension) folder.

I strongly advise you to install the package via `composer` to get the package's dependencies automatically.

```
composer require symfony/twig-bridge:~2.3
```

Further composer will automatically register the classes in the autoloader (`vendor/autoload.php`) for you.

Now you just need to add the extensions to twig as described in the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#using-extensions).

```
$twig->addExtension(new \Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\YamlExtension());
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you.Also with the risk of sounding dimwitted: is it possible to configure twig so that you don't have to load the extension everytime like the built-in extensions?

Answer (score 1):

A complete example, with an extension class and a quick extension (a new filter) :

```
<?php

require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

$loader = new Twig_Loader_String();
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

// here we add the extension class (taken from @nifr answer)
$twig->addExtension(new \Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\YamlExtension());

// here we add a new filter quickly
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('paragraph', function ($argument) {
    return "<p>{$argument}</p>";
}, array('pre_escape' => 'html', 'is_safe' => array('html')));
$twig->addFilter($filter);

// demo
echo $twig->render('{{ "hello" | paragraph }}');
```

Comment: hey man,how is twig_loader_string being used here?i read the documentation but couldn't figure.

Comment: It is used so `$twig->render()` takes a string instead of a file as first argument.